# iOS7 table view embedded in tab bar doesn't display last cell

Tags: storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, ios7

In my storyboard, I have a View controller (embedded in a navigation controller).
Inside the view controller I have a tab bar controller, and inside a tab a table view controller. My problem is that the last row of the table view goes "under" the tab bar of the tab bar controller. This didn't happen if i build my app for iOS 6.

How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with the transparency? I'd like to keep the transparency, but I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try setting your tabbar translucent property.

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent= NO; // Set transparency to no and`

`self.tabBar.translucent= NO; //Set this property so that the tab bar will not be transparent`

Comment: It was already set from Interface builder but i dont know why it didn't work. With your solution it's ok now, thank you!

Comment: I thought we need to set it in run time. I didn't observe the option in Xcode. I will go and search for it now. :)

Comment: wait, i get something very strange here. If my build for my device, it's ok. if i build for the simulator, i get this error for the self.tabBar.translucent = NO; property translucent not found! how can be possible??

Comment: Make sure you are running in iOS7 simulator.

Answer (score 2):

This, as said, will work perfectly. I've just tested it.

```
self.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted and upvoted answers don't work for my setup:

`UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController -> UITableView`

My app's root view controller is a `UITabBarController`. Every tab is a `UINavigationController`, and in one tab, the navigation controller's root is a `UIViewController` with a table view as the main view.

So here's what worked for me: When alloc-initing the UITableView, I compute for the height and set it in the table view's frame. The general formula is `screen height - (status bar height + nav bar height + tab bar height)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` not being applied (or applied correctly) due to the nested structure of your view controller hierarchy.

Try and copy your table into a new `UIViewController` and make sure the checkmark in the `UIViewController`'s identity inspector called "Adjust Scroll View Insets" is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the up-voted answers did not solve it. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21869659/1367622) to a similar question, [Tab Bar covers TableView cells in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325677/tab-bar-covers-tableview-cells-in-ios7).

I solved the issue by manually setting the table view's frame in the table view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method (as suggested by [Matt Quiros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20348066/1367622)) to the height of the screen - (status bar height + nav bar height + tab bar height).

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Adjust height of tableview (does not resize correctly in iOS 7)
    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height = [self heightForTableView];
    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
}

- (CGFloat)heightForTableView
{
    return CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) -
           (CGRectGetHeight([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]) +
            CGRectGetHeight(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame) +
            CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame));
}
```

If anyone finds a better solution to this problem, please share!