# Tab Bar covers TableView cells in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios7, uitableview

I have a custom tableViewController that I'm adding to a TabBarController with

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:someOtherViewController, customTableViewController, nil];
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

The issue I'm having is that the last 1.5 tableViewCells are being covered by the tab bar at the bottom of the screen on an iPhone 4 running iOS7.  When I use the iOS Simulator - iPhone Retina (4-inch) / iOS 7.0 the issue still exists.

What is the correct way to make the tableView line up with the top of the tabBar at the bottom of the screen without using 'magic numbers'?

Comment: i suggest you that create View-controller subclass of UIViewcontroller and add Tableview IBOutlate. via xib or storyBoard and add That created viewController into tabbar controller

Comment: That's exactly the setup right now

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try this for your CustomViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIEdgeInsets adjustForTabbarInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = adjustForTabbarInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = adjustForTabbarInsets;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that, it seems to raise the tableview bound but still about half of a table view cell is covered.

Comment: No, no, it's contentInset. This is actually a UIScrollView property, and since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, you should always be able to edit its contentInset

Comment: @Zenox Had no intention to hurt your brain so I updated my answer :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Just copy pasted it and works great.

Comment: for me it worked well when calling by putting [super viewDidLoad]; at the end of the method.

Comment: This is nice and all, but the scroll bar still disappears behind the Tab Bar... I'm not complaining, but why does that happen?

Comment: Answer from Hans Exabyte below seems more standard to me.

Answer (score 51):

It's an iOS 8 solution but it may work on iOS 7 to: Go to storyboard > select table view controller > uncheck "Under Bottom Bars". That's it!

[image: example]

Comment: Works on iOS 7 and 8 for me, I think this is the more elgant answer.

Comment: Well for the functionality it is the more elegant answer... but at the same time it makes the background of the tabBar gray... which is not what i want.

Comment: it is gray because you have tabBar translucent

Comment: Works on IOS11 too

Answer (score 7):

Setting the `contentInset` of your table view with a `.bottom` value of 49 points should correct this.

Under the right configurations, setting `YES` for the new UIViewController property on iOS 7 called `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` should correct this, but (again) it depends upon a lot of other factors (view hierarchy, parent view controller's settings, et cetera).

Comment: According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) there is no such thing as the automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets property

Comment: It's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`, my apologies.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer doesn't quite work for me--my set up is a little different. I'm programatically creating my view controllers. My app's root is a tab bar controller, one tab is a navigation controller, whose root is a `UIViewController` with a table view as the main view.

What works for me though is when I manually computed the table view's height and set it in the frame when alloc-initing the table view. The general formula is:

> screen height - (status bar height + nav bar height + tab bar height)

Comment: I have the same setup with Matt and somehow this still works in iOS 9+

Answer (score 5):

```
CGFloat bottom =  self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"%f",bottom);
[self.tableview setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottom, 0)];
self.tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottom, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Embed your table controller in a navigation controller. 
1. select the view in story board.
2. On menu bar select Editor -> embed in -> navigation controller.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar view hierarchy to [Matt Quiros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20348198/1367622): UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController -> UITableViewController (embedded as a subview of the UIViewController). The other answers didn't work in my case, and I had to set the table view's frame manually in the table view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Adjust height of tableview (does not resize correctly in iOS 7)
    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height = [self heightForTableView];
    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
}

- (CGFloat)heightForTableView
{
    return CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) -
           (CGRectGetHeight([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]) +
            CGRectGetHeight(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame) +
            CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame));
}
```

If anyone finds a better solution, please share!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work better for you:

After `[super viewDidLoad];`

try the following code:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and use `bottomLayoutGuide` to get the height of the tab bar:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGFloat bottomOffset = self.bottomLayoutGuide.length;

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottomOffset, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though changing the contentInset of your table View is a working solution, I find it better to make sure your table view stops before the Tabbar.

As Paul Newman said, using the bottomLayoutGuide is a good thing, specially if you are using autolayout.
In My case adding a constraint to the bottom of the tableview linking to the top of the BottomLayoutGuide was a clean solution, this is an example with Storyboard, but it can be done in code as well.

[image]

Hope it helps.