# Adding TableFooterView makes my other views Disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

My first problem that i had was that my last UITableViewCell never had a separator which i wanted. I solved it using this code:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Now that worked perfectly however with one problem. when i add that all my other views disappear. Here is a picture of before i use the one line of code above and after:

[image]

[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Set a zero height table footer view, like so:

```
 self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Because the table thinks there is a footer to show, it doesn't display any cells beyond those you explicitly asked for.

Comment: I am thinking it has to do something with my constraints? Because the view is directly below the last cell maybe it bounces of somewhere because a "footerview" is added. Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the viewForFooterInSection function?

Comment: Yes, then the problem occurs where the footer follows me up when i scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Add a vertical spacing of 0 between your table view bottom and the view's top which is placed below it. And you need to set one view's height fixed either for UITableView or UIView. Add this code of line in viewDidLoad. It will display the separator also for last cell.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this help

You have to set translucent property of tab bar controller

see this question to more reference...

[iOS 7 TabBar Translucent issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979281/ios-7-tabbar-translucent-issue)